# File Extension Check fails only for .gif files

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have a problem with my file extension check.
It passes for png, jpg, jpeg files but fails for gif files:

```
if($.inArray(value.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])){
    //Do something
} else{
    alert("invalid file extension");
}
```

What's the problem here? If I use the console in debug mode I can see, that value.name equals "filename.gif"

Thanks for help!

Yanick

Comment: Change your alert to be `alert("Invalid extension: "+value.name.split('.').pop());`

Comment: are you SURE it's `gif` (3 chars) and not something like `gif[space]` (4+ chars)? console.log the split() results and see what's really coming out.

Comment: Yes I am shure it's gif, checked it with different files and also created new ones. @EricLaw also did this, I get "gif"